# regex for integer and .0 number

Tags: regex

I need regex for integer number or decimal number with .0

approved:
35
35.0

not approved:
any other decimal (35.7, 35.989)

Comment: `/\d+|\d+\.0/g`

Comment: If you have access to a programming language, parse the number out of the input string and check if it is divisible by 1. Regex is not a panacea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way:

```
^\d+(?:\.0)?$
```

- `^` - start of line anchor
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `(?:` - start of non-capturing group

  - `\.0` - A literal `.` followed by `0`
- `)` - end of non-capturing group
- `?` - 0 or 1 match of the previous match (the non-capturing group matching on `\.0`)
- `$` - end of line anchor

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/azQ79f/1)